# Previous route showing in current route in Sapper

Tags: routes, sapper, svelte-3

I have two routes `/questions` and `/profile`. In the `onDestroy()` lifecycle event I called `console.log('destroyed')`. When I switch between routes I get 'destroyed' in Chrome console each time.

The problem is that inside `/questions` route, I have checkboxes, binded using `bind:group={multiple_ids}`. So after checking/unchecking a field, when I switch from `/question` to `/profile` route. Contents of `/question` route are showing inside `/profile` route and Chrome console is not showing 'destroyed' anymore after this! This behavior seems very strange to me. I have no idea what is happening. This is a working project. Please solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have transitions in your components? According to this [bug-report](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/814), elements can show up in other routes after navigation. It sounds a lot like the issue you're having.

A solution would be to use the `|local` modifier for your transition attributes. Have a look at the [API docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#in_fn_out_fn) on how to apply it.